# Gitk doesn't show full diff

Tags: git, gitk

Say I have a repository `repo` with two folders:

- `foo`
- `bar`

Say I want to see all commits in folder `foo`. I type `gitk -- repo/foo` and voilá, there they are.

*Problem: All commits displayed in the graphical output silently omit any file that resides outside of `foo`, say, in `bar`.*

How can I make `gitk` only display commits for a directory, but yet show the full changelog of a commit?

Comment: I was hoping the option `--full-diff` would work, but it doesn't appear to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is probably to click on `View` and then in the context menu, choose `All files` (vs `command line`, which goes back to the restrictions).  Note that the set of selectable commits will change as well, but you will still be on the commit you selected.

(You can also add a new view; each view can have its own selected branches, trees, and so on.)

Comment: This is a little tedious, since I'll now get a list of *all* commits in the repo, but at least I can switch it back manually.